# SharePoint List as Lookup Issue

Tags: 2007, list

I am using SharePoint 2007. I have a list which contains the names of all 50 states in the United States and as such contains a total of 50 items in the list.

I created another list which has a column of Lookup Type which uses the list of states as its data source.

If I don't allow multiple choices, it is rendered as a drop-down list with no options in it. If I allow multiple choices, it is rendered as a side-by-side selector with options in it.

Is there some bug or something that prevents displaying the states in the drop-down list when there's a certain size of data or is it some other issue?

I have other Lookup Type columns in the 2nd list which render properly as a drop down list, but they have fewer items.

Answer (score 1):

If your lookup list has more than 20 items, the select drop down is rendered as an ugly input control in IE olny, other broowsers it renders as a select always.

THere is a jQuery library that will allow you to convert the complex control back into a simple control, [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com).